# Why eclipse always occur an error "An internal error occurred during: "Notifying selection listeners". java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have a big project upon the framework of OROCOS, when I open some CPP file in eclipse, there always been a error of "An internal error occurred during: "Notifying selection listeners".java.lang.StackOverflowError"

I restart the eclipse IDE ,no use, I changed the version of eclipse,such as juno, kepter, Luna, Oxygen, all of them have no difference. I tried to "Index->Refresh all files", no use.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms1Ye.png)

Comment: Raise a bug report with eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered  same problem. Seems like error is triggered by too many compile errors found in one code line.
I had some hard stuff with templates and multiple namespaces. This resulted in about 30 errors in one line.
What helped to me is just fix (or delete) this line.

Answer (score 0):

I've met this problem again.
I've had two classes in one file, when it popped up. So I've decided to split classes to separate files. I've copy-pasted base class to new file. The result surprised me: the old file have cured, and the problem started to show up in the new one. I've ignored it for a while and everything was OK untill I've noticed that changes to the base class do not affect the derived class as they should do. Long story short I've retyped the base class in another file with a different name, and seems like now it works again.